# order detail with sql query in magento?

Tags: magento

hi i have created a custom module in magento. now i need to fetch the order data with user requirement.such as when user enter the from and end date the only those order id will appear.
so i want to run a query in magento which gives me the only those order id. can any one have any idea about this. or please give some suggestion for this

Comment: You should use the default magento sales/order collection and apply your date filters on it

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple...

```
// 1. Create order collection object
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
// 2. Apply your date filter
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
     'created_at', 
     array('from' => '2010-01-01', 'to' => '2010-01-01')
);
// 3. Iterate it for displaying results
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    //...
}
```